# Not able to keep the option selected in drop-down list

Tags: html

I have a drop-down list which POSTs to express and then **redirects to same page**.

1. Now, I want the one valid option to be selected before submitting, hence I added `required` property in `<select>` tag.
2. But, I also want a value to be Selected in the list when page renders

- If first time render, then first option
- If after submitting, the submitted option to be selected by default

Here is the skeleton code

```
<select required data-style="btn-info" name="selectpicker">
        <optgroup label="Select Map">
            <option name="table1" value="Station">Station</option>
            <option name="table2" value="Station2">Station2</option>
        </optgroup>
</select>
```

and the things I tried

```
<option value="" selected disabled>Select station</option>
```

```
<option name="table1" value="Station" selected>Station</option>
```

but none of them fulfills my requirements.

Comment: You don't seem to have either of the option-elements marked as selected https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option Use the selected-attribute to specify which is selected by default. After post to server you need to be able to generate html with correct option-element with the selected-attribute.

Comment: @Esko I had tried them too before. Now edited them into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems were solved by

```
<form action="any" method="any" onSubmit="return fieldCheck();">
```

```
<select required id="collec" data-style="btn-info" name="selectpicker">
    <option value="Select Station" selected disabled hidden>Select City</option>
    <option name="table1" value="Vice City">Vice City</option>
    <option name="table2" value="Delhi City">Delhi City</option>
```

and script

```js
function fieldCheck() {
    var collec = document.querySelector('#collec');
    if(collec.value != "Select Station") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Select a city first!!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using javascript for handling the form just add event.preventDefault() in your onsubmit function so when you submit it won't revert back to default

Comment: The form is POSTing to express.